# Swap Mat Accordion to Mat Tree from Angular Materials

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, tree, accordion

I want to swap Swap Mat Accordion to Mat Tree from Angular Materials.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Current code:

- typescript:

```
export class TablesListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  tables: DefaultTable[] = [];

  constructor(private tableService: TablesService, private activeTableService: ActiveTableService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableService
      .tablesGet()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.subscribe$))
      .subscribe({
        next: (tables: DefaultTable[]) => {
          this.tables = tables;
        },
        error: (error: any) => {
          console.error(error);
        },
      });
  }

  tableElementClicked(event: MouseEvent) {
    const htmlElement: HTMLParagraphElement = event.currentTarget as HTMLParagraphElement;

    this.tables.forEach(table => {
      if (table.name === htmlElement.textContent) {
        this.activeTableService.activeTable.next(table);
        
        return;
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscribe$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

- html:

```html
<div class="tables">
  <mat-accordion class="tables__accordion" [togglePosition]="'before'">
    <mat-expansion-panel class="tables__accordion-panel">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header class="tables__accordion-panel-header">
        <mat-panel-title> Tables </mat-panel-title>
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div class="tables__accordion-panel-content">
        <p>ToDo List</p>
        <p>Custom List</p>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
</div>
```

After changes:

[image]

Code:

- typescript:

```
interface TableNode {
  name: string;
  children?: TableNode[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tables-list',
  templateUrl: './tables-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tables-list.component.scss'],
})
export class TablesListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private subscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();
  tables: DefaultTable[] = [];

  nestedDataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource<DefaultTable>();
  nestedTreeControl = new NestedTreeControl<DefaultTable>(node => new Array(node));

  constructor(private tableService: TablesService, private activeTableService: ActiveTableService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tableService
      .tablesGet()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.subscribe$))
      .subscribe({
        next: (tables: DefaultTable[]) => {         
          this.nestedDataSource.data = tables;
        },
        error: error => {
          console.error(error);
        },
      });
  }

  getChildren = (tableNode: TableNode) => {
    return tableNode;
  };

  hasNestedChild(index: number, node: DefaultTable[]) {
    return node?.length > 0;
  }

  // rest of code ommited
}
```

- html:

```html
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl">
  <p>Tables</p>  
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled></button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node;when: hasNestedChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'Toggle ' + node.name">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.name}}
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

I want to aim same visual result for Mat Tree as for Mat Accordion.
'Tables' label must stay hardcoded - that what makes most problems.
Afer click on 'Tables' list should expand and tables from backend should be shown.

Thanks for any help or advice.